# return Promise when invoking Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke a Lambda function and return a Promise on finish,

but i get the following error:

> "createUser(...).then is not a function"

```
const createUser = (phone) => {
  return lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'createUser',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({"phone": phone})
  }, (err, data) => {
    let payload = JSON.parse(data.Payload);

    if (payload.statusCode != 200) {
      Promise.reject(payload);
    }
    Promise.resolve(payload);
  })
}

createUser('')
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Already tried declaring a new Promise using the

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})
```

but that didn't work also...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

aws-sdk supports promises through a `promise()` property on the object returned from most API methods, like so:

```
const createUser = (phone) => {
    return lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'createUser',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({"phone": phone})
    }).promise();
}

createUser('555...')
.then(res => console.log)
.catch(err => console.log);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Comment: thank you, a few days after I've opened this question I realized that there is a promise() method on most of the aws-sdk functions, and I have refactored the whole app :)

Answer (score 3):

Alright,figured it out...

I haven't returned the promise correctly.

to fix the error, I have declared the lambda.invoke inside of a new Promise,
and then returned the Promise like this:

```
const createUser = (phone) => {
   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    lambda.invoke({
      FunctionName: 'createUser',
      Payload: JSON.stringify({"phone": phone})
    }, (err, data) => {
      let payload = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
      if (payload.statusCode != 200) {
        reject(payload);
      } else {
        resolve(payload);
      }
    })
  })
  return promise;
}
```